# How can I write a macro to import a text file into Excel where the text file to be selected is based on a variable in the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, select, import, vba

I need to select a text file to import into Excel where the name of the text file contains a string of text that matches a cell in the Excel spreadsheet.

Eg.

A cell with a value "D12345"

I need to import a text file into the sheet where the same string (i.e. "D12345") is contained in the name of the text file.

The selection needs to be made from a collection of text files.  Only 1 file in the collection will contain the matching string.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub SimpleFileListre()
Dim s As String, FileName As String
Dim mesage As String
Range("A:A").Clear
s = "C:\TestFolder\*.txt"
sFolder = "C:\TestFolder\"
FileName = Dir(s)
Do Until FileName = ""
    If InStr(1, FileName, "D12345") > 0 Then
        Call GetStuff(sFolder & FileName)
    End If
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
End Sub

Sub GetStuff(s)
    Close #2
    Open s For Input As #2
    j = 1
     Do While Not EOF(2)
            Line Input #2, TextLine
            Cells(j, 1) = TextLine
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    Close #2
End Sub
```